# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' Underscore.js

Tags: underscore.js

I'm getting this error when I copy-paste the underscore.js to my console. [Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvfoW.png) "Uncaught SyntaxError; Unexpected token 'export'"

I tried on both Chrome Version 100.0.4896.127 and Opera LVL3 (core: 85.0.4341.72) if that helps.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For upvotes, add the error text to your question (i.e., copy it from the console or type it yourself) and remove your apology as it is not needed! :-)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Unexpected token 'export'` means that the engine encountered JavaScript's `export` keyword, which is only allowed when you do `<script type=module>`. This means that you probably copied the ESM bundle to your console (`underscore-esm.js`), which is not meant for this scenario.

For copy-pasting into the console, the UMD bundle (`underscore-umd.js`) is more suitable. This will give you a global `_` variable that lets you access all Underscore functions.

When writing JavaScript projects "for serious", you will generally either do something like this:

```js
import _, { times, debounce } from 'underscore';
```

if you are using an ESM platform (which may require setting up an [import map](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-dynamically-import-javascript-with-import-maps) or similar *alias configuration* in some cases), or something like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.3/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```

if you are attaching your dependencies directly to an HTML page.